# How do I write an iterator extension that can be used only with an iterator over some type?

Tags: rust, iterator

I would like to analyze the value of the incoming items and adjust/group outgoing items accordingly. For that, I need to ensure that my extension can only be called on the iterator wrapping items of a particular type.

My naive approach is to pin the item type in my extension trait:

```
trait Tags: Sized + Iterator<Item = i32> {
    fn tags(self) -> TagsIterator<Self> {
        TagsIterator(self)
    }
}
impl<I: Sized + Iterator<Item = i32>> Tags for I {}

struct TagGroup;

struct TagsIterator<I: Sized + Iterator<Item = i32>>(I);
impl<I: Sized + Iterator<Item = i32>> Iterator for TagsIterator<I> {
    type Item = TagGroup;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
let test = vec![0_i32, 1_i32, 2_i32];
test.iter().tags();
```

```
error[E0599]: the method `tags` exists for struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:20:17
   |
20 |       test.iter().tags();
   |                   ^^^^ method cannot be called on `std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<std::slice::Iter<'_, i32> as Iterator>::Item = i32`
           which is required by `std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>: Tags`
           `<&std::slice::Iter<'_, i32> as Iterator>::Item = i32`
           which is required by `&std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>: Tags`
           `&std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>: Iterator`
           which is required by `&std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>: Tags`
           `<&mut std::slice::Iter<'_, i32> as Iterator>::Item = i32`
           which is required by `&mut std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>: Tags`
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to restrict an extension trait's incoming items type?

Comment: `Vec<T>::iter` returns an iterator over `&T`s, not `T`s. `test.iter()` thus returns an `impl Iterator<Item=&i32>`, which may be causing the problem.

Comment: `test.into_iter().tags()`